# JQuery scroll to dynamic id

Tags: jquery

i am trying to scroll to a dynamic id. i am using the following jquery

```
$('.toggle-explanation').click(function() {
   var divID = '#explanation-' + $(this).attr('rel');
   //var divID = '#explanation-' + $(this).attr('id');
   $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $(divID).offset().top}, {queue: false, duration: 900});
   $($(this).attr('rel')).slideToggle(900);
  });

   -----

<a class="toggle-explanation" rel="#explanation-<?php the_ID(); ?>" href="javascript:void(0);">Explanation &gt;</a>
```

i am not sure why it does not work.

Comment: Remove the explanation- part in the divId, now you're getting explanation-explanation-phpid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not working because var divID created by you looks that: "#explanation-#explanation-"

Try this way:

```
var divID = $(this).attr('rel');
```

Comment: thanx, that did work. it opens the explanation but only scrolls to the position with i click the link a 2nd time to close.